# Incompatibility of ols_step_both_p with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, olsrr

I am trying to use `ols_step_both_p` with `group_by` function of `dplyr` package. I am using the following code

```
library(tidyverse)
library(olsrr)

#Do linear regression for all the locations
model = df %>% 
  mutate(Location = factor(Location, levels = unique(Location))) %>% 
  group_by(Location) %>%
  do(mod = lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + x8 + x9 + x10 + x11 + x12, data = ., 
              na.action=na.omit)) 

#Do stepwise regression for 1st location
ols_step_both_p(model$mod[[1]], pent = 0.05, prem = 0.1)
```

It returns me following error

> Error in eval(model$call$data) : object '.' not found

How can I solve this error?

**Data**

```
df = structure(list(Location = c("Location 1", "Location 1", "Location 1", 
"Location 1", "Location 1", "Location 1", "Location 1", "Location 1", 
"Location 1", "Location 1", "Location 1", "Location 1", "Location 1", 
"Location 1", "Location 1", "Location 1", "Location 1", "Location 1", 
"Location 1", "Location 1", "Location 2", "Location 2", "Location 2", 
"Location 2", "Location 2", "Location 2", "Location 2", "Location 2", 
"Location 2", "Location 2", "Location 2", "Location 2", "Location 2", 
"Location 2", "Location 2", "Location 2", "Location 2", "Location 2", 
"Location 2", "Location 2"), y = c(1.65954284204268, 1.58123919015159, 
2.05973017000125, 2.18912673315495, 2.01224505269543, 1.99259958467057, 
2.00078847394452, 1.36897959183673, 1.52340971947847, 0.0261531145981931, 
0.154664774742817, 0.790430042398546, 1.28059309309309, 0.974354066985646, 
1.20366598778004, 1.39269070394898, 1.40758547008547, 1.61010461852513, 
1.62170385395538, 1.62471511775133, 2.38461538461538, 2.42220884742702, 
2.41693907875186, 2.81167789541226, 2.74944214217405, 2.21060782036392, 
2.55440414507772, 2.96888447533929, 2.63223300970874, 2.91519143680527, 
2.7768625982778, 3.56561085972851, 3.11382113821138, 2.9851919008764, 
3.31187669990934, 2.82333333333333, 3.63553943789665, 2.26956784527047, 
2.92354185554548, NA), x1 = c(0, 0, 271.72, 138.49, 0, 9.78, 
59.25, 0, 132.37, 29.14, 127.09, 26.35, 36.34, 22.58, 85.59, 
0, 0, 358.06, 0, 0, 3.33, 0, 0, 0, 5.62, 3.33, 3.23, 16.58, 85.6, 
72.73, 48.72, 29.21, 16.67, 63.12, 53.33, 40, 89.46, 76.35, 16.66, 
47.0397916666667), x2 = c(13.12, 0, 145.91, 131.29, 6.56, 141.93, 
174.52, 0, 104.95, 133.98, 182.68, 121.07, 128.49, 87.64, 99.25, 
0, 0, 124.63, 0, 3.33, 19.58, 32.58, 51.58, 27.4, 12.68, 29.91, 
72.37, 9.34, 22.82, 55.76, 25.9, 11.93, 25.9, 13.33, 29.46, 29.56, 
19.68, 46.24, 19.9, 39.13625), x3 = c(223.84, 59.36, 0, 3.33, 
81.72, 6.45, 13.01, 196.98, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.33, 19.89, 3.23, 79.25, 
118.17, 3.23, 118.28, 121.5, 87.01, 70.46, 54.29, 70.97, 51.81, 
84.69, 66.75, 104.27, 29.21, 52.54, 34.51, 103.44, 139.87, 85.16, 
101.93, 82.36, 79.25, 49.14, 91.62, 43.7104166666667), x4 = c(44.04, 
31.43, 3.33, 0, 16.35, 0, 9.68, 108.28, 22.8, 9.9, 6.67, 6.67, 
0, 10, 0, 19.57, 26.01, 9.9, 32.58, 26.13, 58.46, 12.67, 29.16, 
73.39, 65.45, 68.92, 22.93, 107.04, 97.63, 94.2, 132.53, 112.47, 
95.03, 127.42, 107.53, 107.96, 71.72, 68.38, 123.87, 47.4670833333333
), x5 = c(34.12, 35.23, 39.8, 31, 33.8, 31.6, 33.96, 34.7, 33.2, 
32, 32.3, 32.7, 30.72, 33.44, 31.2, 33.03, 33.73, 32.5, 34.57, 
32.83, 33.5, 32.6, 33.3, 33.3, 32.9, 34.9, 32.4, 34.4, 34, 34.3, 
33.6, 35.7, 33.4, 34.5, 34.2, 35.2, 33.6, 34.6, 34.5, 32.7333333333333
), x6 = c(25.99, 25.55, 22.2, 25.6, 25.36, 24.8, 25.7, 26.4, 
22.3, 23.3, 22.8, 23.1, 25.16, 25.59, 24.82, 25.24, 25.93, 25.11, 
25.54, 25.54, 24.5, 24.4, 25.7, 25.7, 26.9, 24.1, 24.4, 24.4, 
25.4, 24, 23.5, 24.3, 24.1, 23.9, 25.1, 27.2, 25, 24.4, 24.5, 
23.628125), x7 = c(26.26, 26.7, 20.7, 21.1, 25.71, 21.6, 20, 
26.48, 22.9, 21.3, 21.2, 21.5, 22.3, 21.6, 21, 27.12, 27.23, 
22.6, 27.09, 26.29, 24.2, 25.2, 21.9, 22.6, 25.3, 23.4, 22.6, 
25.6, 25, 21.3, 19, 24.7, 21.1, 23.6, 22.7, 20, 20.4, 22.8, 24.2, 
24.10625), x8 = c(21.34, 21.95, 12, 16.9, 22.47, 19, 18, 22.86, 
15.2, 18.2, 17.2, 14.7, 17.7, 19.2, 16.3, 21.88, 21.55, 14.5, 
22.09, 22.1, 16.9, 18.6, 16.9, 19.2, 17.9, 19, 18.6, 17.4, 13.6, 
10, 13.3, 13.3, 14.2, 12, 11.9, 11.5, 10, 12.8, 13.7, 16.5791666666667
), x9 = c(5.46, 5.99, 8.2875, 7.2175, 6.18, 5.5925, 6.3025, 6.565, 
8.2725, 6.4175, 7.0825, 6.915, 6.89, 6.4475, 7.15, 5.945, 6.165, 
10.925, 6.0325, 5.52, 7.7925, 7.5525, 7.4025, 7.985, 8.505, 8.06, 
7.3125, 8.775, 9.615, 9.2025, 8.9075, 8.8675, 8.315, 9.1525, 
8.965, 8.9225, 9.475, 8.87, 8.6175, 8.30661458333333), x10 = c(0, 
0.25, 8.25, 6.25, 0, 10.75, 6, 0, 5.75, 4, 6.75, 4.25, 4.5, 2.5, 
5.5, 0, 0.25, 5.5, 0, 0, 7.75, 8.5, 6.75, 8.75, 10, 5.75, 10.25, 
9.75, 15, 10.25, 9.5, 10.75, 11.5, 12.25, 13.5, 10, 14.25, 13.25, 
11.25, 6.5), x11 = c(66.96, 77.19, 454, 60.5, 40.8, 61.6, 96.5, 
48.37, 100.7, 105.8, 48.5, 70.5, 118.2, 79, 56.6, 60.4, 80.1, 
119.07, 72.92, 213.39, 65.9, 54.2, 50.6, 98.1, 106.3, 77.8, 39.7, 
79.8, 33.2, 71, 49.3, 74, 97, 55.4, 84.8, 116, 51.7, 87.6, 35.2, 
51.4166666666667), x12 = c(227.07, 183.81, 570.7, 160.3, 145.07, 
136.2, 153.9, 149.17, 333.6, 224.4, 106.5, 138.05, 185.8, 176.64, 
227.9, 151.13, 261.67, 273.67, 196.28, 513.67, 156.6, 136.8, 
79.5, 200.6, 286.4, 157.6, 86.3, 164.6, 74.2, 120.7, 111.5, 104.5, 
189.1, 150, 139.2, 206, 82.2, 140.5, 137.6, 101.529166666667)), row.names = c(NA, 
40L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `data` argument from `.` to `df` inside `model`.
The code will look like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(olsrr)

#Do linear regression for all the locations
model = df %>% 
  mutate(Location = factor(Location, levels = unique(Location))) %>% 
  group_by(Location) %>%
  do(mod = lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + x8 + x9 + x10 + x11 + x12, data = df, 
              na.action=na.omit)) 

#Do stepwise regression for 1st location
ols_step_both_p(model$mod[[1]], pent = 0.05, prem = 0.1)
```

**EDIT**
You can use the `plyr` package in R to achieve what you're looking for.

```
model <- dlply(df, "Location", function(df) 
  lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + x8 + x9 + x10 + x11 + x12, data = df, 
                                               na.action=na.omit))
```

It will give output like this:

```
$`Location 1`

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + x8 + x9 + 
    x10 + x11 + x12, data = df, na.action = na.omit)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           x1           x2           x3           x4  
 -1.456e+01   -8.337e-05   -5.070e-03   -3.452e-04   -5.945e-03  
         x5           x6           x7           x8           x9  
  1.573e-01    4.143e-01    8.837e-02   -8.740e-02   -3.271e-02  
        x10          x11          x12  
  1.884e-01   -2.184e-03    1.565e-03  


$`Location 2`

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + x8 + x9 + 
    x10 + x11 + x12, data = df, na.action = na.omit)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           x1           x2           x3           x4  
   4.514414    -0.026296    -0.003970     0.002311    -0.003639  
         x5           x6           x7           x8           x9  
  -0.201435    -0.045264    -0.023305    -0.096439     1.047886  
        x10          x11          x12  
   0.067007     0.009080    -0.006701  


attr(,"split_type")
[1] "data.frame"
attr(,"split_labels")
    Location
1 Location 1
2 Location 2
```

And then you can use `ols_step_both_p` like this:

```
ols_step_both_p(model$`Location 1`, pent = 0.05, prem = 0.1)
ols_step_both_p(model$`Location 2`, pent = 0.05, prem = 0.1)
```

Comment: I have done this. But if you use `model$mod[[1]]` and `model$mod[[2]]`, then you will find that the outputs are same. For more details you can visit [this](https://github.com/rsquaredacademy/olsrr/issues/192).

Comment: That is happening because, if you see `model$mod[[1]]` or `model$mod[[2]]` output, data is listed as `.` inside `Call`.

Comment: One possible way would be to filter the data and create separate `df` for `Location1` and `Location2`.

Comment: Separately that can be done. But I have many locations. So, I wanted to automate it.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please check if it solves your problem.

Comment: Have you chacked the output of ```ols_step_both_p(model$`Location 1`, pent = 0.05, prem = 0.1)``` and ```ols_step_both_p(model$`Location 2`, pent = 0.05, prem = 0.1)```? I am getting same output.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `C(p)` values are different

Comment: I have reported the problem to the developer of `olsrr` package. He has solved it. Using the development version from GitHub solves the problem.

Comment: Alright! Way to go!